# Filter between two values directus

Tags: database, api, directus

I would like to make a request to recover data with directus.
I want to retrieve data between two values, I looked at the documentation and I found _between but the problem I did not understand how to put the values ​​at the end of the url.

here is an example url

```
http://localhost:8055/items/product?fields=title,price,id,surface,city.name,price,thumbnail,rooms&filter[price][_between]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved after many tries. Here's what to do

```
http://localhost:8055/items/product?fields=title,price,id,surface,city.name,price,thumbnail,rooms&filter[price][_between]=50,100000
```